# How to update the view of a particular position of a recycler view which is not currently in focus on the screen?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am actually making some visibility changes to items that are clicked of the recycler view. But when the user clicks on one object and then clicks on the other object then the previous object should come to its initial state. 
The manager.findViewByPosition(position) is working fine if the view is in focus of the screen but I am not able to get the view if the element is not in current focus.
For example:- the user clicks on 1st(position) item then clicks on the last position then the findViewByPosition returns a null.

Please help and let me know if there is some other way of doing it.

The expected result should be the view of the last item to be refreshed but it's not happening for the views that are not in the current focus of the screen.

Below is my code snippet. Updated with what you suggested.

```
public class BodyPartWithMmtRecyclerView extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<BodyPartWithMmtRecyclerView.ViewHolder>
{
   //variables defined. 
   int selectedPosition = -1;
   static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   //All the view items declared here.
   ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
  //All the views are defined here.
  }
} 
public BodyPartWithMmtRecyclerView(List<BodyPartWithMmtSelectionModel> bodyPartsList, Context context){
//array list initialization and shared preference variables initialization
}

public BodyPartWithMmtRecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //Creating a new view.
}

 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final BodyPartWithMmtRecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
BodyPartWithMmtSelectionModel bodyPartWithMmtSelectionModel = bodyPartsList.get(position);
    holder.iv_bodypart.setImageResource(bodyPartWithMmtSelectionModel.getIv_body_part());
    holder.tv_body_part_name.setText(bodyPartWithMmtSelectionModel.getExercise_name());

if(selectedPosition!=position && selectedPosition!=-1){
 //updated the elements view to default view. Like made the visibility and other changes here.           
    }

 //some click listeners on the sub-elements of the items. Like textviews, spinner, etc
holder.iv_bodypart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((BodyPartSelection)context).setFabVisible();
            if(selectedPosition!=-1){
                ((BodyPartSelection)context).visibilityChanged(selectedPosition,position);
           /*here what I was doing is whenever the user clicks on an item I check weather a previous item is clicked or not then if yes then I send the position to a function that makes it to default but the issue was that if the item is not in the focus of the screen the findViewByPosition returns null.*/

            }
            selectedPosition = position;
            bodypartSelected = holder.tv_body_part_name.getText().toString();
            holder.iv_bodypart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.rl_left_right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });


   //and other listeners below 

}

 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return bodyPartsList==null?0:bodyPartsList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

}
```

VisibilityChanged function

```
public void visibilityChanged(int position, int clicked){

          View view = manager.findViewByPosition(position);
          if(view!=null) {
            Log.i("inside","visibility change");
            ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.bodypartImage);
            //other elements and changing the visibility of elemets to default.
           }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code? We have to seen if you're using the RecyclerView in the right way by using a collection of items (that you what to display using the Recycler) and and use them to fill the placeholder...

Comment: You can set and get data using Pojo class, Suppose you click on some 1st item of recyclerview and there is 100s of data and you want to change last item, then you can update list and notifiydatasetchange with the set new arraylist to recycler view

Comment: Actually, there is no change in the data set I just want to update the visibility of the last clicked view(its child views). For example, I have three text view inside every element and I want to disable there visibility once clicked on the new item.   @ChiragSavsani

Comment: It would be good if you post your code snipe for the recyclerview adpter section here. Further, do you want to keep one selected item in some specific look and rest as default and once selected other item then the previously selected item will come to default look and newely selected will show as selected look?

Comment: Yes @HariNJha exactly what I want.

Comment: I have posted my answer below. Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have updated my code based on the snippet you updated. Please don't change the visibility condition if-else I have added with any different logic which I saw in your code snippet. As you did, it will not update both selected and default view as RecyclerView reuse the view layout. So if the condition is not proper, you may see multiple items as selected or some other types of unwated behaviour.

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final BodyPartWithMmtRecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
    BodyPartWithMmtSelectionModel bodyPartWithMmtSelectionModel = bodyPartsList.get(position);
    holder.iv_bodypart.setImageResource(bodyPartWithMmtSelectionModel.getIv_body_part());
    holder.tv_body_part_name.setText(bodyPartWithMmtSelectionModel.getExercise_name());

    if(selectedPosition == position){
        //updated the elements view to SELECTED VIEW. Like made the visibility and other changes here.           
    } else {
        //updated the elements view to default view. Like made the visibility and other changes here.
    }

     //some click listeners on the sub-elements of the items. Like textviews, spinner, etc
    holder.iv_bodypart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((BodyPartSelection)context).setFabVisible();


            /Comment by Hari: Don't try to change the visibility of default as it will be done automatically after calling notifyDataSetChanged(). */
            if(selectedPosition!=-1){
                ((BodyPartSelection)context).visibilityChanged(selectedPosition,position);
           /*here what I was doing is whenever the user clicks on an item I check weather a previous item is clicked or not then if yes then I send the position to a function that makes it to default but the issue was that if the item is not in the focus of the screen the findViewByPosition returns null.*/

           /*Comment by Hari: This snippet is valuable which is missing as you are getting null issue here.
           However Don't try to change the visibility of default as it will be done automatically after calling notifyDataSetChanged(). */

            }
            selectedPosition = position;
            bodypartSelected = holder.tv_body_part_name.getText().toString();
            holder.iv_bodypart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.rl_left_right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //Keep this as last statement in onClick
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

   //and other listeners below 

}
```

Let me know your further response.

Comment: I am trying this solution, I will definitely let you know. Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: It is working great with the first and last element but for others, it is not working that robustly for other elements as the onBindViewHolder is not always called when scrolled but is usually called when it reaches to the end and the start of the list.

Comment: Thanks @Chirag Savsani, I have missed to put notifyDataSetChanged() after if else. You need to add this to see the effect. Bdw Ankush, if still you are facing issue then I would suggest you to put your code snippet here of your adapter class because using this logic, your requirement should work.

Comment: As @Chirag Savsani pointed out, I have updated my answer. Let me know further.

Comment: But we cannot call this method while recycler view is computing a layout or scrolling.   @Hari N Jha

Comment: As you have confirmed, you want to updated only one position at a time may be on some particular condition or user interaction. But as you just commented, I am not sure why you need to call this when there is scrolling or computing. I can try to help you further only if you show your code snippet. Thanks.

Comment: Do I have to put the entire code or just explain what I am doing there in parts? Thank you for your response.

Comment: It would be good if you put code of your adapter class and related snippets where you think the flow is related to the issue.

Comment: Thank you @Hari N Jha for your response. I have updated the query with some code snippets hope you understand what I am doing please let me know where I am doing it wrong.

Comment: I have updated my answer as per your provided code snippets. I have mentioned in my done and will try to focus that don't try to change the condition of if-else as we need both condition for selected and default to be there otherwise you will not get a proper solution. Further, don't try to change the view from inside the onClick() rather use notifyDataSetChanged() and it will be done automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your response I will try this solution.

Comment: @AnkushSharma, please update if it solved your issue. Thanks.

Comment: No @Hari N Jha it did not solve the problem. I am solving this by changing the view by not doing any visibility changes inside the adapter element, rather I am planning to show popup dialog on click of the list item and then making all the choices and visibility changes done by the user.
Thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Hari N Jha's Answer.

Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` when you update anything. E.g

```
    int selectedPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //....

        if(position == selectedPosition) {
            //Add background color change of your layout or as you want for selected item.
        } else {
            //Add background color change of your layout or as you want for default item.
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged(); //Call notifyDataSetChanged() here after done all the stufs
        //...
    }
```

Comment: But we cannot call this method while recycler view is computing a layout or scrolling.

Comment: As you have confirmed, you want to updated only one position at a time may be on some particular condition or user interaction. But as you just commented, I am not sure why you need to call this when there is scrolling or computing. I can try to help you further only if you show your code snippet. Thanks.

Comment: Yes exactly. without code snippet, we can not help you further.